# $http call in angular js filters

Tags: angularjs

I want a $http call in a custom filters that returns a value its not working(Asynch) and not returning a value.i want to do it by filters only.is it possible;

Here is my code:

```
  .filter('getSportName', ['$http', '$filter','BASE_URL','$rootScope','adapter',function ( $http, $filter,BASE_URL,$rootScope,adapter) {
    return function(id){
      var request = {
        method: 'get',
        command: 'SportsMasters/'+id,
      };
      adapter.call(request)
        .then(function (data) {
         var selectedSport = data;
          var name=data.sportstitle;
          return name;

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(">>>>>>>error ",err);

        })

    }
  }])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use filters that way. Filters are for transforming inputs based on optional params.

The problem here would be that you're immediately returning a promise from the filter function. And that's nothing Angular can deal with as a result from a filter.

My suggestion therefore would be this - fetch the result first, work with the filter based on the result:

As you'd be bombarding your server quite a bit with requests whenever you try to filter your data.

Comment: i have more than 1000 nested records in my view .each record have a sport id.i want to get sport name on basis of sport id from $http call ...here only i can use a filter or a function call

Comment: You can nest $http calls.